# Unresolved reference of a method call in another method

Tags: go, goland

I want to call two methods(seedAccounts and initializeBucket) from the Seed method. Is there a way to do it? It keeps saying "Unresolved reference".

Here is the code

```
type BoltClient struct {
    boltDB *bolt.DB
}

func (bc *BoltClient) Seed() {
    initializeBucket() //unresolved reference initializeBucket
    seedAccounts() // unresolved reference seedAccounts
}

func (bc *BoltClient) initializeBucket() {
    //Code
}

func (bc *BoltClient) seedAccounts() {
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initializeBucket()` and `seedAccounts()` are methods of type `BoltClient`, quick fix:

```
func (bc *BoltClient) Seed() {
     bc.initializeBucket() 
     bc.seedAccounts()
}
```

Comment: What i assume, it is called as depedency injection for golang